# how to connect and deploy a flutter app to "real server" base on .netcore+iis+sqlserver

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, iis, web-deployment, windows-server

I have a project to make a website and application, and i did it by .net core and sql server and deploy it on iis and finally real server and special domain. Also i did my flutter app and tested it by url on local host ('http://192.168.1.110/project_Name/Controller/method_Name') to get connect with my database and it answered currectly,
But now i have a problem with my url to connect real server and create data on sql on server side(i can not find any special pattern to write url with domain-server-port and ...).
i dont know how to do it ,for example Should i add my fluttr app by iis or just change (new type of)url to get connection with my website backend ??
all of the sources learn about localhost.

could some one answer me about it or introduce appropriate source to guide??

Comment: It's always better to not connect to the database directly, having an API in middle would help.

Comment: I didnt mean that, i try to connect API first before data base, connecting from app to API is my main question .

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to serve the flutter app as static files, you can achieve that by copying the output of `flutter build web` to the wwwroot folder of the ASP.Net core project should look something like this :

[image]

And then you need to serve it by adding the static files middleware in your request pipeline in your Startup.cs Configure method using the `app.UseStaticFiles();`

You should then access your flutter web application following the URL :

```
https://yourdomainname/index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying, flutter project is an app not web app. the main problem is belong to 404 error when i post some method to domain. it worked on iis on localhost of my PC but i can not post any method from outside of my .net core project on server(even from postman). I have  published it regularly.